# How to check if generic K is part of generic M | Typescript Generic | Redux

Tags: typescript, generics, redux, typescript-generics

## Hi

I'm trying to reduce Bolilderplate in my react application. I am using the Redux state and have decided which Redux structure to use(see Context). Now I want to make it smaller. For this I have created a generic actionCreator. My problem is to find the desired generic syntax.

## Generic Action Creator

This is my generic approach on an action generator.

```js
export class genericAction<M, K> extends Action {
    public reducer = (state: M) => ({ ...state, ...this.payload });

    constructor(public readonly type: string | undefined, public payload: K) {
        super();
    }
}
```

At the moment it is only possible to merge the states, but I am aiming for an optional parameter that is a function. This function will then allow me to perform custom state merges (e.g. state.count + payload). But this is a different topic.

## Problem

My problem is that I could use `{ fubar: number}` instead of `{ loading: boolean }`. Obviously fubar is not part of my ProductStateModel.

```js
const someAction = new genericAction<ProductStateModel, { loading: boolean }>(ProductListActionTypes.REQUEST_START, { loading: true });
```

## Question

I want to use only attributes of the ProductStateModel as type for the generic K.
Pseudo Code:

```
genericAction<M, K is type of M> extends Action
```

The general idea is to create the action with the following types and parameters:

- StateModel
- ProductListActionType
- Payload

Is that possible? Or is there common/alternative solution? I am fine with changes to the StateModel if needed. I am new to redux and want to do it right. I tried to get Pick<T, K> in the generic method, but by now I am not sure if that is even possible the way I need it or maybe I should just go to sleep :D

Thank you for any hints and help

---

## Context

This is my starting point

```js
// State
export interface State {}

export interface ProductStateModel extends State {
    products: Array<ProductDTO>;
    loading: boolean;
    error: string;
}


// Product Actions
export abstract class Action {
    public readonly type: string | undefined;
    protected constructor() {
        return Object.assign({}, this);
    }
    abstract reducer(state: State): State;
}

// First of 3 Actions. They are all very similar. The generic function should replace all of them.
export class ProductListRequest extends Action {
    public readonly type = ProductListActionTypes.REQUEST_START;
    public reducer = (state: ProductStateModel) => ({ ...state, loading: this.payload.loading });

    constructor(public payload: Pick<ProductStateModel, 'loading'>) {
        super();
    }
}

// Reducer
export const productListReducer = (state: ProductStateModel = defaultProductState, action: Action) => {
    return isNil(action.reducer) ? action.reducer(state) : state;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export class genericAction<M> extends Action {
    public reducer = (state: M) => ({ ...state, ...this.payload });

    constructor(public readonly type: string | undefined, public payload: Partial<M>) {
        super();
    }
}
```

I removed the second type and added Partial to the payload generic type. In my head I wanted to restrict the allowed attributes like I did in the original approach with `Pick<ProductStateModel, 'loading'>` but then I realized that this is not needed. The new call of the generic class is the only place where I define which attributes this action needs and this is fine.